# How to continue a loop with try catch?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, do-while

I've been trying for a few hours now, but I can't manage exceptions in loops while!
Basically I would like the loop to activate when there is an error! 
Ps: it's a mini restaurant that I'm making to train on Java since I'm a beginner !

Here is where I would like to put the exceptions to redo it on the different parts of the code:

```
                        do {


                    System.out.println("\nMain menu:\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < mainMenu.length; i++) {
                        int menuNumber = i + 1;
                        System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ mainMenu[i]);
                    }

                    try {
                        System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                        mainMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here    



                            if(mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) > mainMenu.length || mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) <= 0) {
                                mainWhilePass = false;
                                mainMenuChoice.remove(mainI);
                            } else {
                                mainWhilePass = true;

                            }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    }


            } while (!mainWhilePass);
```

Here is full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class McHouseCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(System.in);

        String mainMenu[] = {"McBurger", "McTrio", "Fries" , "Nothing"};
        String drinkMenu[] = {"Coca", "Pepsi", "Coffe", "Nothing"};
        String sauceMenu[] = {"Ketchup", "Moutarde", "Mayo", "Nothing"};
        int mainI = -1;
        int drinkI = -1; 
        int sauceI = -1;

        ArrayList<Integer> mainMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> drinkMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> sauceMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean mainRetake, drinkRetake, sauceRetake;
        boolean mainWhilePass = false, drinkWhilePass = false, sauceWhilePass = false;
        String mainRetakeAnswer, drinkRetakeAnswer, sauceRetakeAnswer;

        System.out.println("Welcome to McHouse ! "+"\n");

        /* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu */

        do {
            mainI ++;
            do {


                    System.out.println("\nMain menu:\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < mainMenu.length; i++) {
                        int menuNumber = i + 1;
                        System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ mainMenu[i]);
                    }

                    try {
                        System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                        mainMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here    



                            if(mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) > mainMenu.length || mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) <= 0) {
                                mainWhilePass = false;
                                mainMenuChoice.remove(mainI);
                            } else {
                                mainWhilePass = true;

                            }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    }


            } while (!mainWhilePass);


            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                mainRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                mainRetake = true;
            } else {
                mainRetake = false;
            }
        } while (mainRetake);

        System.out.println("");

        /* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu */

        do {
            drinkI ++;
            do {

                System.out.println("\nDrink menu:\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < drinkMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ drinkMenu[i]);
                }

                System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");

                drinkMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());

                if(drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) > drinkMenu.length || drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) <= 0) {
                    drinkWhilePass = false;
                    drinkMenuChoice.remove(drinkI);
                } else {
                    drinkWhilePass = true;

                }


            } while (!drinkWhilePass);


            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                drinkRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                drinkRetake = true;
            } else {
                drinkRetake = false;
            }
        } while (drinkRetake);

        System.out.println("");

        /* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu */

        do {

            sauceI ++;
            do {

                System.out.println("\nSauce menu:\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < sauceMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ sauceMenu[i]);
                }

                System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                sauceMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());

                if(sauceMenuChoice.get(sauceI) > sauceMenu.length || sauceMenuChoice.get(sauceI) <= 0) {
                    sauceWhilePass = false;
                    sauceMenuChoice.remove(sauceI);
                } else {
                    sauceWhilePass = true;

                }


            } while (!sauceWhilePass);


            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                sauceRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                sauceRetake = true;
            } else {
                sauceRetake = false;
            }
        } while (sauceRetake);

        /* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy */

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Great! ");
        System.out.println("You purchached: \n");

        System.out.println("Main Menu");
        for(int i = 0; i < mainMenuChoice.size();i++) {

            int r = mainMenuChoice.get(i) - 1;
            System.out.println( (i+ 1) + "| "+ mainMenu[r]);
        }

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Drink");
        for(int i = 0; i < drinkMenuChoice.size();i++) {

            int r = drinkMenuChoice.get(i) - 1;
            System.out.println( (i+ 1) + "| "+ drinkMenu[r]);
        }

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Sauce");
        for(int i = 0; i < sauceMenuChoice.size();i++) {

            int r = sauceMenuChoice.get(i) - 1;
            System.out.println( (i+ 1) + "| "+ sauceMenu[r]);
        }

        /* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end */

        scanLine.close();
        scanInt.close();

        System.out.println("\n\nProgarm end");


    }

}
```

Here is the final code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class McHouseCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(System.in);

        String mainMenu[] = {"McBurger", "McTrio", "Fries" , "Nothing"};
        String drinkMenu[] = {"Coca", "Pepsi", "Coffe", "Nothing"};
        String sauceMenu[] = {"Ketchup", "Moutarde", "Mayo", "Nothing"};
        int mainI = -1;
        int drinkI = -1; 
        int sauceI = -1;

        ArrayList<Integer> mainMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> drinkMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> sauceMenuChoice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean mainRetake, drinkRetake, sauceRetake;
        boolean mainWhilePass = false, drinkWhilePass = false, sauceWhilePass = false;
        String mainRetakeAnswer, drinkRetakeAnswer, sauceRetakeAnswer;

        System.out.println("Welcome to McHouse ! "+"\n");

        /* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu *//* Main Menu */

        do {
            mainI ++;
            do {
                System.out.println("\nMain menu:\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < mainMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ mainMenu[i]);
                }
                try {
                    System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                    if (scanInt.hasNextInt()) {
                        mainMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here

                        if(mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) > mainMenu.length || mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) <= 0) {
                            mainWhilePass = false;
                            mainMenuChoice.remove(mainI);

                        } else {
                            mainWhilePass = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.err.print("Not valid choice: " + scanInt.next());
                        mainI -= 1;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    scanInt.next();
                }

            } while (!mainWhilePass);
            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                mainRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (mainRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                mainRetake = true;
            } else {
                mainRetake = false;
            }
        } while (mainRetake);

        System.out.println("");

        /* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu *//* Drink Menu */

        do {
            drinkI ++;
            do {
                System.out.println("\nDrink menu:\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < drinkMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ drinkMenu[i]);
                }
                System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");

                drinkMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());

                if(drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) > drinkMenu.length || drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) <= 0) {
                    drinkWhilePass = false;
                    drinkMenuChoice.remove(drinkI);
                } else {
                    drinkWhilePass = true;
                }
            } while (!drinkWhilePass);
            do {
                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                drinkRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
            if (drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                drinkRetake = true;
            } else {
                drinkRetake = false;
            }
        } while (drinkRetake);
        System.out.println("");
        /* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu *//* Sauce Menu */
        do {
            drinkI ++;
            do {
                System.out.println("\nDrink menu:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < drinkMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ drinkMenu[i]);
                }
                try {
                    System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                    if (scanInt.hasNextInt()) {
                        drinkMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here
                        if(drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) > drinkMenu.length || drinkMenuChoice.get(drinkI) <= 0) {
                            drinkWhilePass = false;
                            drinkMenuChoice.remove(drinkI);

                        } else {
                            drinkWhilePass = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.err.print("Not valid choice: " + scanInt.next());
                        drinkI -= 1;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    scanInt.next();
                }








            } while (!drinkWhilePass);


            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                drinkRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (drinkRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                drinkRetake = true;
            } else {
                drinkRetake = false;
            }
        } while (drinkRetake);

        System.out.println("");


        /* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy *//* What did you buy */

        do {
            sauceI ++;
            do {


                System.out.println("\nSauce menu:\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < sauceMenu.length; i++) {
                    int menuNumber = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(menuNumber + ": "+ sauceMenu[i]);
                }


                try {
                    System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
                    if (scanInt.hasNextInt()) {
                        sauceMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here

                        if(sauceMenuChoice.get(sauceI) > sauceMenu.length || sauceMenuChoice.get(sauceI) <= 0) {
                            sauceWhilePass = false;
                            sauceMenuChoice.remove(sauceI);

                        } else {
                            sauceWhilePass = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.err.print("Not valid choice: " + scanInt.next());
                        sauceI -= 1;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    scanInt.next();
                }








            } while (!sauceWhilePass);


            do {

                System.out.print("\n[Yes | No] Do you want to retake: ");
                sauceRetakeAnswer = scanLine.nextLine();

            } while (!sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));

            if (sauceRetakeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                sauceRetake = true;
            } else {
                sauceRetake = false;
            }
        } while (sauceRetake);

        System.out.println("");


        /* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end *//* Program end */

        scanLine.close();
        scanInt.close();

        System.out.println("\n\nProgarm end");


    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want the loop to "activate when there is an error"?  Do you want to throw or catch exceptions?  And please fix the indentation of your code and remove any excessive empty lines

Comment: the while is triggered, but it doesn't ask the user to enter an answer anymore! it just makes an infinite loop!

Comment: Still doesn't explain how you want to handle exceptions. And don't explain in the commenst, update your question instead.

Comment: I've modified the code so that you can understand it better, but when I execute this code, it just creates an infinite loop! ='(

Comment: I still don't really get what you want to do but I see that your logic for handling the response is to complicated. Instead of adding the response to the list,  mainMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt()); and then getting it and possibly removing it  from the list you should read into a local int variable that you validate and if it is ok then you add it to your list. So `int choice = scanInt.nextInt();` and then validate and add `choice`

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to validate ...

Comment: You have some validation already, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I want to check if the user enters an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must test the type before reading the scanner and even if there is an error, you must read the input :

```
try {
    System.out.print("The number of your choice: ");
    if (scanInt.hasNextInt()) {
        mainMenuChoice.add(scanInt.nextInt());      // exeption here

        if(mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) > mainMenu.length || mainMenuChoice.get(mainI) <= 0) {
            mainWhilePass = false;
            mainMenuChoice.remove(mainI);
        } else {
            mainWhilePass = true;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("not valid choice: " + scanInt.next());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    scanInt.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! bro! Your the best

Comment: Yeah but i dons't understand how to do that! I'm learning Java and i am a beigner but i think to remove 1 to ```mainI``` after each error ?

Comment: Yes this work !

Comment: Here is  the finale code:

Comment: Right ! I forgot mainI, but now all is OK ... ?